# Google App Script - Insert Data Into Next Column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This script fetches the data from the sheet and insert it into a new sheet. I want the second function to insert into the third row each time.

I want the result to be -

Timestamp | Impressions | CTR

```
function AggregateData() {
Impressions();
CTR();
}

function Impressions() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Metrics");
var source = sheet.getRange("G16:H16");
var values = source.getValues();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Aggregate");
values[0][0] = new Date();
sheet.appendRow(values[0]);
};

function CTR() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Metrics");
var source = sheet.getRange("F16:G16");
var values = source.getValues();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Aggregate");
values[0][0] = new Date();
sheet.appendRow(values[0]);
};
```

This code appends the second function in the second column itself below the result of the first function.

Comment: Looking for some clarifications: 1) By second function do you mean CTR()? 2) CTR() And Impressions() add to different sheets so how can the CTR add below what was added by Impressions?

Comment: Sorry, I've adjusted the code. It should be on the same sheet - Aggregate. The order would be Timestamp(col A) Impressions( col B) CTR (col C). I assume the date() would have to be removed from CTR function since it's already being populated by impression(). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Another confusion thing in your question is at the start of your question you say "I want the second function to insert into the third row each time". However, from the above comment I think you meant to say "insert into the third column". Am I right or am I missing something? From you code I gather you are trying  to swap column F and Column H from the metrics sheet into aggregate sheet

Comment: Yes, the metric sheet is a live tracker. I want to store that data periodically into the aggregate sheet. The code i have does the job but it inserts both impression and ctr into the same column one after the other, that way i cannot create any sensible graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will copy your data to a new sheet in the order you want. However, I have reduced it to one function. The reason your code puts the new data in a new row is this line:

```
Sheet.appendRow(data)
```

puts the data you supply to a new row which is empty. That is also the reason why i have combined the two functions into one.

```
function AggregateData() {
Impressions();
}

function Impressions() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Metrics");
 var source = sheet.getRange("F16:H16");
 var values = source.getValues();
 var pasteValues = []  // create new array which will hold the data you need to be pasted into the aggregate Sheet
 pasteValues[0] = [] // Adding a second dimesion to the array
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Aggregate");
 // below 3 lines does the switch of data and adds the time stamp
 pasteValues[0][0] = new Date();
 pasteValues[0][1] = values[0][2]   //Copy the col h (impressions value) value into the new array
 pasteValues[0][2] = values[0][1]   //Copy the col G (impressions value) value into the new array
 sheet.appendRow(pasteValues[0]); //Append the new array into the sheet
};
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. How would I add another column after this in the same array ?

Comment: to add another column just add a new data in the array pasteValues, like so pasteValue[0][3] = "new Col data here"

Comment: Thankyou J. This was bothering me the whole day.